# Overwrite an image/pixel data in the dicom file using dcmtk

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, medical, dcmtk

I use dcmtk to read a dicom file and extract the image into a .tiff format. After doing some image processing I have an image which I would like to save in the source dicom file.That is overwriting the old image/pixel data with my new ones, while keeping rest of the data(uid,patient name,,etc) same.

I use the following code to read dicom

```
OFCondition status = src_fileformat.loadFile(src_path);

    if (status.good())
    {
        Sint32 instanceNumber = 0;
        if (src_fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetSint32(DCM_InstanceNumber, instanceNumber).good())
        {
            cout << "instance Number N: " << instanceNumber << endl;
            sprintf(instanceNum, "%d", instanceNumber);
            printf("%s\n", instanceNum);
        }

        else
            cerr << "Error: cannot access Instance Number!" << endl;
    }
    else
        cerr << "Error: cannot read DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")" << endl;

    src_dcm = new DicomImage(src_path);
    if (src_dcm != NULL)
    {
        if (src_dcm->getStatus() == EIS_Normal)
        {
            if (src_dcm->isMonochrome())
            {
                src_dcm->setMinMaxWindow();
                Uint8 *pixelData = (Uint8 *)(src_dcm->getOutputData(16 /* bits */));
                if (pixelData != NULL)
                {
                    src_dcm->writeBMP("source.tiff", 24);  /* do something useful with the pixel data */
                }
            }
        }
        else
            cerr << "Error: cannot load DICOM image (" << DicomImage::getString(src_dcm->getStatus()) << ")" << endl;
    }
```

After image processing I have an image that I want to overwrite onto this source dicom file. I looked into image2dcm,but I couldn't get the correct syntax/method to do. any one help me out.. :)

Edit-1

```
Image2Dcm i2d; 
I2DOutputPlug *outPlug = new I2DOutputPlugSC(); 
 I2DImgSource *inputPlug = new I2DJpegSource(); 
 E_TransferSyntax writeXfer; 
 inputPlug->setImageFile(jpgFile); 
DcmDataset *dataset = NULL; 
OFCondition result = i2d.convert(inputPlug, outPlug, dataset, writeXfer); 

   // Saving output DICOM image 
  if (result.good()) 
      { 
        dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_PhotometricInterpretation,"RGB"); 

            DcmFileFormat dcmff(dataset); 
    result = dcmff.saveFile(dcmFile, writeXfer); 
       }
```

I tried the above shown syntax,but couldn't exactly understand it

[image: This is the processed image]

This is the processed image(above)

[image: Original dicom image]

This is the original dicom image that I want to overwrite. Guys ,any idea or help??

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `image2dcm`?

Comment: I Have shown the syntax that I tried...

Comment: First of all, taking source code snippets and copy them together will not work (not in your case, but also not in general). Your sample code doesn't make any sense to me. Also keeping all UIDs is no good idea at all.

I would recommend that you clearly specify what you input data is and what your output data should be, i.e. what your processing step changes. E.g. you are mixing BMP and TIFF images... did you ever read about the DICOM pixel data format?

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach should be:

1. load the DICOM dataset from file
2. replace the pixel data in the dataset
3. modify various other element values (e.g. SOP Instance UID)
4. save the modified DICOM dataset to a new file

In case of uncompressed images, the second step could be performed in the same manner as the third step, i.e. by an appropriate call of a putAndInsertXXX() method on the dataset. Of course, the element value of the Pixel Data attribute should be in correct DICOM format. See [DICOM standard](http://dicom.nema.org/standard.html) part 3 and 5 for details.

Comment: I understand the approach. Steps 1,3 and 4 I can manage to do.But its the 2nd step that blocks me.

Comment: Regarding step 2: This is why I added the last paragraph to my answer. Just add the pixel data array (in your case monochrome 8 or 16 bit values) to the PixelData element using putAndInsertUint8Array() or putAndInsertUint16Array(). And, please make sure that the values in the array are consistent with the other DICOM element values in group "0028".